Проблема с токеном пользователя при попытке публикации поста VK API
У меня микропроект, фактически чисто код на пайтоне без визуала. Я пытался сделать возможность публикации постов, но выкидывает ошибку.

{'error_code': 15, 'error_subcode': 1133, 'error_msg': 'Access denied:
no access to call this method. It cannot be called with current
scopes.',

Права выдал (offline,wall), но всё равно выкидывает ошибку
# вк постинг
user_id = '*'
version = '5.131'
access_token = '*'
message = "Это пример поста, опубликованного через Python!"
owner_id = 823397911
# URL для запроса
url = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post"

# Параметры запроса
params = {
    "access_token": access_token,
    "v": "5.131",  # версия API
    "owner_id": owner_id,
    "message": message,
}

# Выполнение POST-запроса
response = requests.post(url, params=params)

# Обработка ответа
data = response.json()
if "response" in data:
    print(f"Пост опубликован! ID поста: {data['response']['post_id']}")
else:
    print(f"Ошибка: {data.get('error', 'Неизвестная ошибка')}")

Если можете, напиши порядок действий, что делать, для того что бы получить адекватно токен пользователя, что бы можно было постить

Возможно дело вот в этом https://qna.habr.com/q/1333574

Да, надо было паспорт им скинуть. Спасибо тебе

Надо было авторизоваться в вк - ввести паспорт для верификации, что бы полностью пользоваться апи
